# Can I see who has downloaded a shared file?

Tags: dropbox, sharing, download

I am the proud owner of a Dropbox Plus account. I recently shared a .zip file and need to know whether it has been downloaded. I really don't care about how many times it has been downloaded, or by whom (I only shared it with one person) but just a yes/no.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Dropbox Community](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Installation-and-desktop-app/Dropbox-Pro-How-to-track-downloads/td-p/68586) dated 04-08-2015 08:17 AM:

> Q: how do I track downloads of any given file that I've uploaded to my account?
>
> A: You can't, Dropbox doesn't provide that feature.

There may be workarounds however. An insecure site has offered two:

> 1) Short URL services like Bitly and Goo.gl will track how many times
>   the links are clicked, showing you the count of how many times your
>   file has been clicked on.
>
> 2) Although Dropbox doesn’t have a downloaded link count, it does have
>   the Dropbox API which allows developers to build plugins to help you
>   do that.

Comment: I saw that post and am wondering if anything has changed in two and a half years?